Plotting financial data Renko-style in gnuplot
I've got OHLC data for the S&P 500 that I would like to plot as a so-called Renko plot ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renko_chart ) in gnuplot.  I have transformed the OHLC data to fixed-size bricks represented in data.dat as the upper and lower diagonal corners of rectangles.  Here's a notional example:
# x1, y1, x2, y2
0 6 1 4
1 8 2 6
2 10 3 8
3 12 4 10
4 14 5 12
5 12 6 10

And then so far I can actually get them onto a plot using the following script:
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600
set output 'renko_chart.png'
set grid

set style fill solid
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2:1:3:2:4 with boxxy

Which produces the following:

What I would like to do is colour "up bricks" green, and "down bricks" red.  Furthermore, I would like to include a date along the X-axis, without affecting the horizontal scale of the bricks.  To get a clearer idea of what I mean, here is an image from the wikipedia article:

Note the date along the bottom, and how the axis scale varies across the width of the image.  Towards the left, we see a period of about 6 days take the same amount of space on the chart as a period of just a few hours to the right.  The idea is that the price action is decoupled from the time frame, and it is the axis that scales reactively to the data.
Is this possible in gnuplot?

Could you please provide a larger amount of data including the date, e.g. like the data for the Wikipedia graph for testing? So, then we don't have to create/invent it ourselves. I guess the bigger challenge than the box coloring is the irregular date/time.

Here is another suggestion. You are actually starting with some kind of OHLC data. Here, for illustration purpose, some random input data for testing is generated within the script (with just one y-value) and looks like the following:
2024-05-23 19:17:19      93.1655
2024-05-23 20:17:19      94.1
2024-05-23 21:17:19      94.008
2024-05-23 22:17:19      94.5589
2024-05-23 23:17:19      94.1284
2024-05-24 00:17:19      93.9924
2024-05-24 01:17:19      93.8272
2024-05-24 02:17:19      94.3609

The data in $Renko looks for example like this, where column 1 and 2 contain the date where the brick started, column 3 contains the y-value and column 4 contains -1 and +1 depending on whether data in this brick was decreasing or increasing, respectively.
2024-05-18 12:17:19      96.9638        1
2024-05-20 00:17:19      99.4638        1
2024-05-20 07:17:19      96.9638       -1
2024-05-21 18:17:19      94.4638       -1
2024-05-22 11:17:19      91.9638       -1
2024-05-23 02:17:19      94.4638        1

Some comments:

I very much hope that I implemented the Renko principle correctly (please double check)
the Renko brick height is defined by h, here h = 2.5.
in order to reduce the number of plotted xtics you use a second "dummy" plot command using xtics() (check help xticlabels) and every(check help every).
Not sure if this is easy to understand. If you need more explanations let me know.

Script:
### Renko style plot
reset session

myFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 2000
    t0 = time(0)-1e7
    y0 = 100
    plot '+' u (strftime(myFmt,t0+$0*3600)):(y0=y0+rand(0)*2-1) w table
unset table

colX = 1
colY = 3
h    = 2.5   # Renko brick height

set table $Renko
    plot $Data u (strftime(myFmt,timecolumn(colX,myFmt))): \
         (y=column(colY), $0==0 ? (s0=s1=1, y0=y) : 0, dy=y-y0, y0): \
         ((newBrick=abs(dy)>h) ? (y0=y0+sgn(dy)*h, s0=s1, s1=sgn(dy)) : 0, s0) \
          with table if newBrick
unset table

N           = |$Renko|       # number of Renko bricks
Tx          = 7              # number of approx. xtics
M           = int(N/(Tx-1))  # show only every M-th xtic
myXtic(col) = strftime("%Y\n%m-%d",strptime(myFmt,strcol(col)))   # xtic format

set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 0.3
set xrange[:] noextend
set offsets graph 0.02, graph 0.02, 0, 0
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 2,1

    set format x "%Y\n%m-%d" timedate
    plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myFmt)):3 w l lc "blue"

    set format x "\n" numeric
    plot $Renko u 0:3:(0.5):(h/2.): \
         ($4>0 ? 0x00cc00 : 0xff0000) w boxxy lc rgb var, \
         '' every M u ($0*M):3:xtic(myXtic(1)) w p ps 0
unset multiplot
### end of script

Result:
Top graph: input data. 
Bottom graph: Renko bricks (note the irregular time scale on x-axis)


This is excellent, thank you!  I will have to spend some time to fully grok that plot command.

@nathanvy you're welcome! Actually, when I looked at the script again, I found that it can be simplified with the reduction of xtics. Check help every.

@nathanvy sorry, I looked a the script once again, and I guess there was a mistake about the offset of the bricks. So, I tried to fix this. As a consequence there was the issue/question about the coloring of the bricks. If the current brick is lower/higher than the previous one the brick is colored red/green, respectively. Since the first brick has no previous one it is defined as always green.

First attempted answer deleted as incorrect
Amended answer
Since you are pre-processing the data, let's choose a convenient input format for gnuplot. As I now understand it after reading the description of Renko plots on Wikipedia, there is no need to save the left and right coordinates of each box.  All boxes are the same width. So I think ideally the easiest format for gnuplot read in would be:
high low timestamp for a falling price and low high timestamp for a rising price.  That way all the necessary information for each box is encoded on a single line.  For the purpose of a quick example I label each box with the timestamp as given in the file, but you might want a more complicated filter function that for instance only produces a label if the day has changed, or at the start of the week, or in a different time format than the input.
$DATA << EOD
115.5 105.5 "06-21-2024 11:00"
105.5  95.5 "06-21-2024 16:00"
105.5 115.5 "06-23-2024 12:00"
105.5  95.5 "06-24-2024 10:10"
105.5 115.5 "06-25-2024 13:30"
115.5 125.5 "07-01-2024 10:00"
125.5 135.5 "07-03-2024 16:00"
135.5 145.5 "07-05-2024 16:00"
145.5 155.5 "07-05-2024 16:00"
EOD

set linetype 101 lc "dark-red"
set linetype 102 lc "forest-green"
unset key
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 1.0
format(col) = strcol(col)       # could be a more complicated filter
                                # and reformat time representation
set xtics rotate by -90.
set xrange [-1:25]

plot $DATA using 0:1:1:2:2:($1>$2 ? 101 : 102):xtic(format(3)) with candlestick lc variable

I am not sure what is the best approach to placing vertical bars at week or month boundaries because these may not correspond to a box at all.  My first thought is to set the grid to draw grid lines for the x2 axis and add a separate plot clause that generates an x2 tick mark if and only if the month has changed.  Since grid lines are drawn only where there is a tick mark, this should work.
set link x2
set x2tics
set grid x2
set grid linewidth 1 linecolor "black" dashtype "."
set tics nomirror

# This function returns 1 if the month has changed since the last call,
# 0 if it has not changed.  Date format is assumed to be "MM-DD-YYYY".
last_month = -1
function $newmonth(date) << EOF
    this_month = int(date[1:2])
    if (this_month == last_month) {
        return 0
    } else {
        last_month = this_month
        return 1
    }
EOF

plot $DATA using 0:1:1:2:2:($1>$2 ? 101 : 102):xtic(format(3)) with candlestick lc variable, \
     $DATA using ( $newmonth(strcol(3)) ? column(0) : NaN ):(0):x2ticlabel("") axes x2y1 with dots 


Note:  This script produces warning messages "add_tic_user: list sort error" when run.  This doesn't seem to harm anything but at the moment I can't explain what is triggering them or how avoid that.  You could add a command unset warnings if they are too annoying.

I'm afraid a Renko plot is not the same as a regular candlestick plot.  A given candlestick represents the price movement in a fixed amount of time, whereas a renko brick represents a fixed amount of price movement, irrespective of the time it takes.  One brick can take mere seconds to form, and the next consecutive brick could take days or weeks.

I apologize for failing to follow the link you provided to find the full definition of the Renko plot. I went by the appearance of the graph you provided.  I will try again if you clarify how your transformed data captures the direction of change and how you attach a timestamp to it.

Well, the transformed data is merely the top and bottom price levels of each brick, and the direction is inferred by those levels relative to those of the previous brick.  Here is another article that might help:  https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/renkochart.asp
As for the timestamp, I can attach it any way that will work for gnuplot, as I'm fetching the data from an API and chewing on it locally.  It's common to see e.g. dashed vertical lines indicating weeks, or days, or months, etc.
